# Angular API PUT-DELETE methods keep returning 404 Not Found

Tags: angularjs, api

this is happening despite not having any issues with the actual client calls and the server implementation of these API methods, any suggestion more than welcome !!  see below

Client Function Implementation inside Angular Controller

```
 function updateData() {
  dataService.put("/api/Product/" +
        vm.product.ProductId,
        vm.product)     
    .then(function (result) {
      // Update product object
      vm.product = result.data;

      // Get index of this product
      var index = vm.products.map(function (p)
      { return p.ProductId; })
          .indexOf(vm.product.ProductId);

      // Update product in array
      vm.products[index] = vm.product;

      setUIState(pageMode.LIST);
    }, function (error) {
      handleException(error);
    });
}
```

API Implementation

```
 [HttpPut()]
public IHttpActionResult Put(int id,
            Product product) {
  IHttpActionResult ret = null;
  PTCViewModel vm = new PTCViewModel();

  vm.Entity = product;
  vm.PageMode = PageConstants.EDIT;
  vm.Save();

  if (vm.IsValid) {
    ret = Ok(product);
  }
  else if (vm.Messages.Count > 0) {
    ret = BadRequest(ConvertToModelState(vm.Messages));
  }
  else {
    ret = NotFound();
  }

  return ret;
}

[HttpDelete()]
public IHttpActionResult Delete(int id) {
  IHttpActionResult ret = null;
  PTCViewModel vm = new PTCViewModel();

  // Get the product
  vm.Entity = vm.Get(id);
  // Did we find the product?
  if (vm.Entity.ProductId > 0) {
    // Delete the product
    vm.Delete(id);

    ret = Ok(true);
  }
  else {
    ret = NotFound();
  }

  return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was using a new version of Angular, all API methods calls are successful as long as the Angular version is 1.x and not 2.x, this is because the syntax to make the PUT and the DELETE calls in Angular 2.x is different and that explains why these end points were returning a 404 Not Found error.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the whole url of your api endpoint here:

`"/api/Product/"`

something like:

`"http://your-api-base-url/api/Product"`